# Вывести значение в необходимом формате php

Tags: php, вывод, форматирование

Есть значение в БД номера телефона в формате 380501234567
Требуется вывести это значение на экран в формате (050) 123-45-67

Пока только понял как удалить первые два символа, это:

```
 $phone = '380501234567';
 $format_phone = substr($phone, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отвечая на вопрос ТС

> Спасибо большое, я так и реализовал. Просто думал есть более изощренный метод)

```
<?php

// начальное значение, проверки на корректность формата опущены
$phone = '380501234567';

/*
  Матчим регуляркой, используя именованные подмаски (именованные подшаблоны)
  `?:` - эта подмаска не будет извлечена в результирующий массив $m
  `?<code>`
  `?<group1>`
  `?<group2>`
  `?<group3>` - будут извлечены с ключами code, group1, group2, group3
  @see http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php
*/
preg_match('~^(?:[0-9]{2})(?<code>[0-9]{3})(?<group1>[0-9]{3})(?<group2>[0-9]{2})(?<group3>[0-9]{2})$~', $phone, $m);

/*
  Извлекаем значения массива в переменные
  Это не обязательно, возможно использовать $m['code'], $m['group1'], $m['group2'], $m['group3']
*/

extract($m);

/*
  Преимущество использования `sprintf`:
  1. шаблон номера телефона '(%s) %s-%s-%s' удобен для визуального восприятия
  2. этот шаблон возможно перенести в конфигурацию модуля, с возможностью редактирования администратором сайта без поиска по коду.
  Другими словами, '(%s) %s-%s-%s' использовать как параметр шаблона, который можно переопределить без вмешательства в код
*/

// выводит: (050) 123-45-67
$phoneTemplate = '(%s) %s-%s-%s';
echo sprintf($phoneTemplate, $code, $group1, $group2, $group3);

// выводит: <span class="text-muted">(050)</span> 123-45-67
$phoneTemplate = '<span class="text-muted">(%s)</span> %s-%s-%s';
echo sprintf($phoneTemplate, $code, $group1, $group2, $group3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = str_split($phone);
echo '('.$arr[2].$arr[3].$arr[4].')'.$arr[5].$arr[6].$arr[7].'-'.$arr[8].$arr[9].'-'.$arr[10].$arr[11];
```

Comment: str_split не нужна. `echo '('.$phone[2].$phone[3].$phone[4].')'.$phone[5].$phone[6].$phone[7].'-'.$phone[8].$phone[9].'-'.$phone[10].$phone[11];`

Comment: Не нужна- к строке можно обращаться как к массиву.

Comment: Спасибо большое, я так и реализовал. Просто думал есть более изощренный метод)

Answer (score 0):

```
function phone_number($sPhone){ 
    $sPhone = preg_replace("[^0-9]",'',$sPhone);
    $sPhone = substr($sPhone, 2);
    if(strlen($sPhone) != 10) return(False); 
    $sArea = substr($sPhone, 0,3); 
    $sPrefix = substr($sPhone,3,2); 
    $sNumber = substr($sPhone,5,2); 
    $sEnd = substr($sPhone,7,2);
    $sPhone = "(".$sArea.")".$sPrefix."-".$sNumber."-".$sEnd; 
    return($sPhone); 
} 

$phone = '380501234567';
echo phone_number($phone);
```

Comment: Спасибо, реализовал методом ниже.